# Redshift Constraints (Primary Key and Foreign Key Constraints)

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am new to Redshift when pushing the data in Redshift, where created the primary key as Vin(Vehicle Identification Number). Even when pushing the same key twice not getting any constraint exception instead same data being saved as record.

And when doing with Foreign key constraint again getting the same issue. Am I missing any configurations for enabling the contrints in db ?

Comment: Since it has been explained by Tim below, I won't repeat the obvious. However, refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_examples.html#r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW-create-a-table-with-an-identity-column to create something which would ensure uniqueness of your records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-defining-constraints.html):

> Define primary key and foreign key constraints between tables wherever appropriate. Even though they are informational only, the query optimizer uses those constraints to generate more efficient query plans.
>
> Do not define primary key and foreign key constraints unless your application enforces the constraints. **Amazon Redshift does not enforce unique, primary-key, and foreign-key constraints.**

If I read this information correctly, the workaround you should follow is to check in your application layer that each VIN number to be inserted is unique.